# Angular material tooltip does not display as expected

Tags: angular, angular-material, tooltip

I've been rummaging around various tutorial sites trying to get material tool tips to work. Super frustrating because it looks really easy. The console displays no errors or warnings. I'm using Angular 11. It is my understanding that once I've imported the MatTooltipModule into my app.module.ts then this functionality will be available for all components in the same module.

```
npm list @angular/core
finfo@0.0.0 C:\source\finfo
+-- @angular/core@11.2.9
`-- codelyzer@6.0.1
  `-- @angular/core@9.0.0
npm list @angular/material
C:\source\finfo
`-- @angular/material@11.2.8

....app.module.ts....
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material/tooltip';
....app.module.ts....
imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),

....store.html....
<div>
  <button matTooltip="Info about the action"
      matTooltipPosition="above"
      class="example-button">
      Action
  </button>
</div>
```

- [Tooltip | Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/examples)
- [Simple YouTube Video showing how easy it is](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8c88JdTXSkw)

**Update**: The answer provided by Zunayed Shahriar is correct. One small addendum, for what ever reason, my project started working with the tooltip *after I moved the @import statement up to the top* of the .css file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working fine for me.

Make sure that you import material CSS (depending on your theme) at your `styles.css` file.

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

Demo at [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6gbcsz?file=src/styles.css).

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: So that goes in the main style.css file? Either that's not it, or there's something more.

Comment: No, only `styles.css` or `styles.scss`.

Comment: Check the demo. There are nothing more.

Comment: Thanks, the demo works great. But I still can't get into my existing project....there's something keeping it from working.

Comment: Could you upload your project at Stackblitz?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It's not my project and belongs to a corporation. But you gave me a working example. I will go through and see if I can work it out. Thanks!

Comment: So, in desperation. I moved the @import statement from the bottom of .css to the top. now it works. Something in there must have collided somehow.

Comment: That's great. Good job.